# how to hide SPUserResizableView with tag in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiview

Hi I have a method in which I have created 3 views on a click;

```
-(void)method{

for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
NSLog(@"i is: %d",i);

NSLog(@"i is: %d",i);
userResizableView = [[SPUserResizableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake   (100,41,60,60)];
userResizableView.tag = i;

imageVw1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:userResizableView.bounds];
imageVw1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redacted2.jpg"];
imageVw1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
imageVw1.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
imageVw1.alpha = 0.93;  // for opacity
userResizableView.contentView = imageVw1;

userResizableView.delegate = self;
[userResizableView showEditingHandles];
currentlyEditingView = userResizableView;
lastEditedView = userResizableView;
[self.view addSubview: userResizableView];
[userResizableView release];


}   
}
```

Now in another method I want to hide these views what I created last.
but I am  not able to do it. I am hiding my view is like-

```
-(void)Hide_method{
// int type instance variable, and a=0; in viewdidload;
userResizableView.tag = a;
userResizableView.hidden = YES;
a++;
}
```

But only one view is hide and the rest are remaining, no matters how amny times I clicked Hide_method, only one view is hide.

My question is that how to hide last view what I created last. Means views hide like 3,2,1,0. On every time when I clicked hide_method.

Any Idea or suggestions would be highly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide `unique tag` to not `clash` with any `other subview` of `self.view` with `same tag` like say any number `999 +`.

Make changes accordingly:

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
  SPUserResizableView *userResizableView = [[SPUserResizableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,41,60,60)];
  userResizableView.tag = 999+i;

  ..........
  ..........
}
```

Now `hide method` would be:

```
-(void)Hide_method{
  // find SPUserResizableView with unique tag
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
  if(i == 2){
    SPUserResizableView*userResizableView = (SPUserResizableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:999+i];
    userResizableView.hidden = YES;
  }
}
```

**EDIT** : To `restore` `frame` to `origina`l store while `allocating view`

```
CGRect prevFrame = userResizableView.frame //take frame while allocating userResizableView
```

Now `restore` whenever you wanted to `original` `frame` like this:

```
SPUserResizableView*userResizableView = (SPUserResizableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:999+2]; //get last userResizableView
userResizableView.frame = prevFrame;
```

Comment: Hello Sir, only your code is working but it hides all the three views, not the last view, then second last view then first view.

Comment: Yes its working ,I want to change frame also. means my views has resizable, if we pull view one it has increase X-horizontally, Y- vertically. So how can I manage my views co-ordinates? menas type of undo, suppose befoe touching the view frame were (100,200,150,150) and after (400,300,250,400). I want undo so that my frame back to (100,200,150,150). how can I do this?

Comment: - (void)userResizableViewDidBeginEditing:(SPUserResizableView *)userResizableView {
    [currentlyEditingView hideEditingHandles];
    currentlyEditingView = userResizableView;
}

- (void)userResizableViewDidEndEditing:(SPUserResizableView *)userResizableView {
    lastEditedView = userResizableView;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([currentlyEditingView hitTest:[touch locationInView:currentlyEditingView] withEvent:nil]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

Comment: yes sir, I want back to my previous frame but the previous frame button is diffrent button, not the undo button , undo button is for hiding the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)Hide_method{
 // int type instance variable, and a=0; in viewdidload;
   //userResizableView.tag = a;
   SPUserResizableView *_view = (SPUserResizableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:a];
   userResizableView.hidden = YES;
   a++;
}
```

Comment: when I do this only one view hide rest are unhide. when I click again this method no view are hide they are still showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)Hide_method{

   //UIView *v = [self.view viewWithTag:a];

    SPUserResizableView *v = (SPUserResizableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:a];

    if(v)
        [v removeFromSuperview];

   a++;
}
```

Comment: when I do this all the screen got black because this line  [v removeFromSuperview];  hide the all view , not the last view only.

Comment: this will remove only a view with tag `a`. Not other views.

Comment: If a=3; then it will hide only tag=3 but not doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Method to remove view having tag=a

```
for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews])
    {
       if (subview.tag == a)
          {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
          }
    }
```